# upload file using AFNetworking , server detects empty stream

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

i'm using this code to upload a file to the server , the stream is not detected on the server , the problem is that i use the same code but in a different project and it works perfectly ! I've included the appropriate headers ! what is going on ? i've spent the last couple of hours working on this problem please help

```
-(void)upload
{

NSString *st = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"R" ofType:@"caf"];
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:st];

AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.116:8084/RasaylServer/"]];

NSString *action = @"SendStreamMessage";

NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[parameters setObject:@"209" forKey:@"param1"];
[parameters setObject:@"205" forKey:@"param2"];
[parameters setObject:@"01/12/2012 15:13" forKey:@"param3"];


NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:action parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
                                  {

                                      [formData appendPartWithFileData:d name:@"a" fileName:@"Test2" mimeType:@"audio/x-caf"];

                                  }];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:myRequest]; 
[operation setCompletionBlock:^(){


} ];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[queue addOperation:operation]; 
[operation start];

operation.completionBlock = ^{   


    if ( operation.error == nil )
        NSLog(@"%@", operation.responseString); 
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@", operation.error);
    }

};



}
```

Comment: Have you checked the `NSData *d` isn't null and has data ?

Comment: it isn't nill it contains actual data !!

Comment: I am also facing same problem with m4a audio file any solution